# How to unsubscribe from the collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor

My publications:

```
Meteor.publish('items', function() {
    return Items.find({}, {skip: randomNumber, limit: 100});
});
```

My subscription code happening when a button is clicked (in templates.event)

```
Meteor.subscribe('items');
Items.find().fetch();
```

However, the problem is that items isn't refreshed with the new data, but new data is appended to the old list instead. What can I do to unsubscribe the old data?

Comment: Here you have example which works: http://meteorpad.com/pad/fwka2h9mAi2vLFysv. Just cancel subscription before subscribing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[When you call `Meteor.subscribe` it will return a subscription handle.](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe)

You call `stop` on the handle to cancel it.

eg, in your event helper

```
if (SomeGlobalVar){
  SomeGlobalVar.stop();
}
SomeGlobalVar = Meteor.subscribe('items');
```

---

[The other way is to run the subscription inside `Deps.autorun`;](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun) it will automatically clean up old subscriptions.

eg, in you event handler

```
Session.set('subscribe', true);
```

Elsewhere in your code:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){ 
  if (Session.get('subscribe')){
     Meteor.subscribe('items');
  }
});
```

If you call `Session.set('subsribe', false);` Meteor will automatically cancel/clean-up that subscription to `items`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like there is a bit of a confusion here, when you are connecting to a reactive data source you are not subscribing to specific data, so when new records are added ofcourse they are appended to your data through that connection.

If I understood your question and you want the new data to completely replace the old data I advise you not to build your template around the Collection but rather build it around a cached version of the data (which will kept in an object and made reactive using Deps), that way you will have total control over the data displayed.

Comment: Not a bad advice, however, when there are thousands of items, it's not a great solution for obvious reasons.

Comment: the query supplied in the question is limited to 1K results so I assumed we will only be dealing with 1K items at a time.